# How to install nuget package in ASP.NET Core project by the CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I'd like to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles to ASP.NET Core project.

Is there another way rather than editing manually the .csproj file?
If I do `nuget install` it installs it in the current project folder and no change is applied to the .csproj file.

The OS is *nix one so I'm using VSCode and a terminal/console.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The .NET Core SDK which has support for the new Sdk style .csproj files allows you to do this from the command line if you are using a .csproj file.

```
dotnet add <PROJECT> package [arguments] [options]
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles -v 1.0.1
```

If you are using project.json files then there is no command line support for that as far as I am aware.

Comment: While trying `dotnet add --help` command, I get an error `No executable found matching command dotnet-add`. I have installed dotnet core sdk 2.0.0 alpha from [here](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/master/dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest.exe) before using this command. Any idea on this?

Comment: You need to edit your system Path variable to have C:\Program Files\dotnet\

Comment: Omg ... simple as that ... ! Thanks Matt! I was looking for some documentation but didn't find any.